# Change search button color in keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have made an `EditText` in order to search for something.

The EditText looks like this:

[image]

The xml of this is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Et_Search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/et_rounded"
    android:hint="@string/Activity_Search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingStart="56dp"
    android:paddingEnd="64dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Since im using `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`, the keyboard that opens when I type looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there is an option to change the color of the circle from green to some other color?

It seems like this green is some Primary color of the app however I don't have this color anywhere.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may have already explored that you can modify the action button from the keyboard, by setting imeOptions. But you cannot override Icons, colors or backgrounds or the keys of the **System provided Soft Keyboard**.

To do so you may have to implement your custom keyboard. like so you can modify everything in keys of that **Custom Keyboard View**.